# QML: prevent ListView from returning at beginning on model change

Tags: listview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

When I try to display data through a `ListView`, everytime the model is updated the view returns to the beginning.
Is there a way to make `ListView` handle the model updates without changing the `visibleArea` of the inner `Flickable` (or changing it in a reasonable way)?
Ideally, the same area should remain visible.

Here a minimal example where you can see that behaviour: if you scroll down in `flickable` (on the left) and in `listView` (on the right), when the timer is triggered the first one will stay where you left it, the second one will go back to beginning.
[QML online live example](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=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-Xm6tcHdxOZeYpDip5x9nox6cJPRJLIf1+1xZFZ9JH45XJ5u21Y1ugjIDzhaGNjlLQNzAVBIkhSY9yztag6CYCEey9B9NCXA8NxxPAZjwi8CTbD9TTLINJVDJw2xrYo4HKSoHnQUFaFbScOy7bdJzgfsRSHZERzbWcoRE35viAA)

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    id:root

    property int model: 10
    property int delegateHeight: height/10*0.8
    property int delegateSpacing: height/10*0.2

    color: "#afafaf"
    anchors.fill: parent

    Timer {
        interval: 5000
        repeat: true
        running: true

        onTriggered: root.model++
    }

    Flickable {
        id: flickable

        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        clip: true
        contentHeight: root.delegateHeight*repeater.count

        Repeater {
            id: repeater

            model: root.model

            delegate: Rectangle {
                x: 0
                y: (root.delegateHeight+root.delegateSpacing)*index
                width: flickable.width
                height: root.delegateHeight
                color: "#abcdef"

                Text {
                    text: index+1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView

        x: parent.width/2
        y: 0
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        clip: true
        model: root.model
        spacing: root.delegateSpacing

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: root.delegateHeight
            color: "#fedcba"

            Text {
                text: index+1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found a sort of workaround, but I don't think it's the right way to go.
Adding to `listView` something like this, will keep the `visibleArea` position on model increasing, but will probably have some drawback when decreasing the counter.

```
        property real lastY: 0

        onContentYChanged: {
            if(!moving){
                listView.contentY = listView.lastY+listView.originY
            }
            listView.lastY = listView.contentY-listView.originY
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you think your workaround is the right way to go?

Comment: I think it could misbehave if, while the view is showing the bottom of the content area, the content shrinks, like lowering the model count in the above example. Probably I'll have to take into account the size of the content while calculating the new content position. Tomorrow I'll try to demonstrate my point.

Comment: It's possible you may need to do something extra for that case, but I wouldn't consider this a workaround at all. I think that's probably the only way to accomplish what you want. When the model changes, the ListView has no idea what part of the new data you want to see, so you have to manually scroll it, which seems to be what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted the workaround presented to handle also the shrink case.

Basically, every time the user *moves* the content, the component stores the new position.
When the content moves by itself, like for a change in the model, the component restores the last position setted by the user, avoiding placing it outside the view.

To achieve this behavior something like this should be a added to `ListView`:

```
        property real lastY: 0

        onContentYChanged: {
            if (!moving) {
                listView.contentY = Math.max(0, Math.min(listView.lastY, listView.contentHeight-listView.height))+listView.originY
            }
            listView.lastY = listView.contentY-listView.originY
        }
```

Working reviewed example [here](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMArAFAkBKApujAIYB2A5gDaVwDeJc3cwAJgC4oECDDI84YYWEqwAnr3rwQEPpWYC4BAAxceUiDPmL4a1o1oxKACUrBGACxiaHdxzAD0OgFTa8ADj1uAyMYBWAlODNKCysAZTBadAjGFzcnL21fPBxxHnQIZmhNACIAYloAMyqqkqC4BnQHaABnPErgZg1JWihKJTzuABVQWQ56iQirKAA3Wm6ibSWJnj6ZS00YKBRKFe5t%20noUze3dvbgIeiGoe0ZZSkE4YVE8FTMAanf6gF9BuAAxZgYTC0ABGrHGEkmj0qQKwYNYfwkAA9NLooTw5GjzgB3fgwByaRJ9JR4PF8AkeXIY7iuexOIm9fowPB09zndBAsAnHYcy5WJS2enOJ4iFnRWI2dIwbxrSiWWR4AooAbnKjraaQmnQzRyhVQJE0t7qXVi16qdSGjEShWaKg0BgsNicbXa1FwdGujFYuAACme4vUMQVQvc7wDeBt8USySYAEpvBE1MjztryQTNLDgQjKGT8Q5UzS2QzRS8o1LhYWMQUilBShVQeg1JU6lWoUNKMj4C6va6rF3NEnO%208CG2JL9e3AJzTp9xfvUADLAFowABqwEoOK1GP4miBK-Xm6tcHdxOZeYpDip5x9nox6cJPRJLIf1%201xZFZ9JH45XJ5u21Y1ugjIDzhaGNjlLQNzAVBIkhSY9yztag6CYCEey9B9NCXA8NxxPAZjwi8CTbD9TTLINJVDJw2xrYo4HKSoHnQUFaFbScOy7bdJzgfsRSHZERzbWcoRE35viAA).

There is probably still room for some improvement, but for the moment this mechanism satisfies my needs.

Comment: Also if you change ```topMargin``` and ```bottomMargin``` of ```ListView``` you will need to adjust this formula accordingly, as ```contentY``` might then be negative.